# macでのSSHの鍵取得で「Too many arguments.」対策

Tags: xcode, github

GitHubを利用して複数のパソコンでXcodeのプロジェクトを使えるようにしたいと思っています。
そこで、ネット上のページを参考にGitHubの設定を進めています。SSHの鍵を取得するためにという段階でターミナルで次のコマンドを実行したところ下記のエラーが出ています。ネットで探しても解決できませんでした。解決法を御教示いただけますか。
（ネットのページは「今日からはじめるGitHub 〜 初心者がGitをインストールして、プルリクできるようになるまでを解説」https://employment.en-japan.com/engineerhub/entry/2017/01/31/110000）

環境は、Sierra 10.12.6  MacBook Airです。

コマンド

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "（自分のメールアドレス）"
```

エラー

```
Too many arguments.
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]...
```

Comment: 残念ながら意図的に引数を余分に渡さない限り、同じエラーは再現できませんでした。もう一度1文字1文字を確実に入力しなおしても、同じエラーが再現できるでしょうか? 特に日本語入力の状態で半角英数字を入力した時など、見えない文字が混ざっていたり、見慣れた半角記号にそっくりな別の文字を入力してしまうことがありますが、その辺は大丈夫でしょうか?

Comment: `-` が enダッシュ 「Option」＋「-(ハイフン)」になっていることは有りえませんか？

Comment: 了解しました。もう一度1文字1文字を確実に入力しなおし、「Option」＋「-(ハイフン)」になっていないようにして入力し直したところエラーは出なくなりました。感謝します。

Answer (score 3):

もう一度1文字1文字を確実に入力しなおし、「Option」＋「-(ハイフン)」になっていないようにして入力し直したところエラーは出なくなりました。